# NUnit is not releasing the .dll for my unit test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have the NUnit GUI runner to run tests on my unit test assembly every time that it is built.  The problem is that when I try to build, the .dll in the Debug folder is in use by NUnit, which prevents it from being built, which prevents the automatic test run.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why are you trying to rebuild when the test runner is still running?

Comment: Sometimes it happens that nunit-agent.exe processes are multiplying and "hanging". The only solution I've found is to occasionaly shutdown NUnit and manually kill orphan nunit-agent processes... However, this never locked my build folders so it might be a different case.

Comment: @HansPassant, the idea here is to leave the NUnit GUI open while writing tests, and running them automagically when I rebuild.

Comment: @Riddari, check the state of option "Shadow copy assemblies" If it's false Nunit will run tests from project output dir blocking files. Otherwise NUnit will copy them to temp folder, and will not block files.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a slightly different approach but along the same lines as @UvarajGopu....

As long as you are using Visual Studio higher than "Express" version, and if you write your UnitTests in a separate project (typically alongside the project being tested, with a ".UnitTests" suffix), then do this:

- Set your UnitTests project as being the StartUp project (right-click in Solution Explorer, "Set as Startup Project")
- In the Project Properties for that project, in the "Debug" tab, choose "Start External Program", and choose the NUnit GUI executable. Put the name of UnitTests assembly in "Command line arguments".

Now you can simply press F5 (to start debugging) which will build your projects, and launch the NUnit GUI for you. This has the added advantage that if your tests fail, you can add breakpoints, and step through using the debugger (without needing to attach the debugger manually).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are building your solution. I suggest you to close the Nunit, which is loaded with your .dll. After unloading try to build, then your build will succeed.

As Nunit is using you .dll. It won't allow your build to be success.

Comment: This is not very convenient.  I am just starting to learn TDD (and I might not be doing it right) I am writing a small test first then coding to make that test pass then writing another small test and so on.  As soon as I code a small bit I want to run the tests to see if it passes.  To have to keep opening and closing the test GUI after every small code change is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago and my final solution was to resign from using NUnit GUI runner and just run them directly from code.

In my project I referenced to NUnit libraries needed by those freshly built dlls plus nunit.core and nunit.utils. The code itself is very simple:

```
TestResult ExecuteTests(string testAssemblyPath) {
    CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
    TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(testAssemblyPath);
    testPackage.BasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(testAssemblyPath);

    RemoteTestRunner testRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
    testRunner.Load(testPackage);

    TestResult testResult = testRunner.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty, true, LoggingThreshold.Warn);

    testRunner.Unload();
    CoreExtensions.Host.UnloadService();

    return testResult;
}
```

The `TestResult` object is very powerful. Among other things, it contains all the results, subresults, tests themselves etc. In order to analyze them, you can either create a simple parser or use one of the possibilities given by NUnit libraries. My favorite is `XmlResultWriter` but there are others available as well. All of them can be found in nunit.util.dll.

Unfortunately, that would still block the loaded dll from being rebuilt. I avoided this problem by running this in a separate AppDomain and unloading this domain after the tests are finished running. Then dll is nicely freed and you can do with it whatever you want.